# How do you assign a slice of numbers to an array in swift

Tags: swift, swift-array

`x` is an object that holds an array called point.

`x` implements the subscript operator so you can do things, like `x[i]` to get the array's ith element (of type T, which is usually an Int or Double).

This is what I want to do:

```
 x[0...2] = [0...2]
```

But I get an error that says `ClosedInterval<T>` is not convertible to Int/Double.

Edit1:

Here is my object `x`:

```
let x = Point<Double>(dimensions:3)
```

For kicks and giggles: define `x` as `[1.0,2.0,0.0]`

I can get the first `n` elements via `x[0...2]`.

*What I want to know is how to update x[0...2] to hold [0.0, 0.0.0.0] in one fell swoop.* Intuitively, I would want to do `x[0...2] = [0...2]`. This does not work as can be seen in the answers. I want to update `x` without iteration (on my end) and by hiding the fact that `x` is not an array (even though it is not).

Comment: Have you tried the map function, or a variant over it?

Answer (score 6):

`[0...2]` is an array with one element which, at best, will be a `Range<Int>` from 0 through 2.  You can't assign that to a slice containing, say, `Int`s.

`x[0...2]` on the other hand is (probably) a slice, and `Sliceable` only defines a `get` subscript, not a setter.  So even if the types were more compatible - that is, if you tried `x[0...2] = 0...2`, which at least is attempting to replace a range within `x` with the values of a similarly-sized collection - it still wouldn't work.

edit: as @rintaro points out, Array does support a setter subscript for ranges – so if `x` were a range you could do `x[0...2] = Slice(0...2)` – but it has to be a slice you assign, so I'd still go with `replaceRange`.

If what you mean is you want to replace entries 0 through 2 with some values, what you want is `replaceRange`, as long as your collection conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollection` (which, for example, `Array` does):

```
var x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
var y = [200,300,400]
x.replaceRange(2..<5, with: y)
// x is now [0,1,200,300,400,5]
```

Note, the replaced range and `y` don't have to be the same size, the collection will expand/contract as necessary.

Also, `y` doesn't have to an array, it can be any kind of collection (has to be a collection though, not a sequence).  So the above code could have been written as:

```
var x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
var y = lazy(2...4).map { $0 * 100 }
x.replaceRange(2..<5, with: y)
```

edit: so, per your edit, to in-place zero out an array of any size in one go, you can do:

```
var x = [1.0,2.0,0.0]
// range to replace is the whole array's range,
// Repeat just generates any given value n times
x.replaceRange(indices(x), with: Repeat(count: x.count, repeatedValue: 0.0))
```

Adjust the range (and count of replacing entries) accordingly if you want to just zero out a subrange.

Given your example `Point` class, here is how you could implement this behavior assuming it's backed by an array under the hood:

```
struct Point<T: FloatLiteralConvertible> {
    private var _vals: [T]

    init(dimensions: Int) {
        _vals = Array(count: dimensions, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    }

    mutating func replaceRange
      <C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == T>
      (subRange: Range<Array<T>.Index>, with newElements: C) {

        // just forwarding on the request - you could perhaps
        // do some additional validation first to ensure dimensions
        // aren't being altered...
        _vals.replaceRange(subRange, with: newElements)

    }

}

var x = Point<Double>(dimensions:3)
x.replaceRange(0...2, with: [1.1,2.2,3.3])
```

Comment: x isn't an array. I was hoping to treat it as one (a n-dim Point). It holds an array.

Comment: Sure, but you still need the equivalent of `replaceRange` - you can forward the implementation on to the contained object.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity FWIW, `Array` implements setter for slice. In your last example, `_vals[subRange] = Slice(newElements)` should work.

Comment: Interesting, so it does, though it doesn't appear to behave the same – if the target range is too small, the array slice setter appears to replace subsequent values with the replacing values even though they weren't in the supplied subscript range.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `subscript(InvervalType)` to handle the case of multiple assignments like this. That isn't done for you automatically.

Comment: Can you say more? I did a Google search for subscript(InvervalType) and found nothing.